# Sorting non-type template parameter pack in C++11 or C++1y?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

In C++11 and/or C++1y:

Suppose I am given a template with a non-type parameter pack:

```
template<int...>
void f();
```

And I'm writing another template that will instantiate it:

```
template<int... x>
void g()
{
    ???

    f<???>();
}
```

I want g to instantiate f with x in sorted order.

That is:

```
g<4,7,2,9,3,7>();
```

should call:

```
f<2,3,4,7,7,9>();
```

Can this be done?  If so, what is the most efficient way (up to constant factors)?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/sort.html ?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: No, I had not.  That looks like what I want, thanks.  If you want to write a quick paragraph about its internal architecture as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you can use Boost MPL's sort "function": http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/sort.html

Given a list of values as template parameters, plus a predicate (which defaults to `less` as is customary), it will produce a "copy" in sorted order.  The claimed complexity is O(n log(n)) "on average", O(n^2) worst-case; making it similar to Quicksort (and in fact, it appears to actually use Quicksort).

You asked about this function's "internal architecture."  About that, I surely have no idea, but given the maturity of Boost MPL and my prior experience using it, I'd say give it a try and if it does what you need, you'll probably find it about as satisfying as you find any other C++ template meta-programming.

Comment: Thanks John.  Actually I want to know how it is done rather than how to do it. :) The difference being somewhat subtle - but I can always eat the source of MPL from here.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 13):

All those answers are so depressingly C++11... lots and lots of template meta-programming spew.
Here is C++14 solution using plain sort constexpr function.

(compile and run with clang + libc++ trunk with std=c++1y)

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>


template<int... x>
void f()
{
   constexpr int x_array[] = {x...};

   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof...(x); i++)
      std::cout << x_array[i] << " ";

   std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, int N>
struct ConstArray
{
   T data[N];
   constexpr T& operator[](int i){return data[i];}
   constexpr const T& operator[](int i) const {return data[i];}
};


template<int... x>
constexpr auto bubble_sort_best_sort()
{
   constexpr int N = sizeof...(x);
   ConstArray<int, N> a = {x...};

  for (int i = 0;  i < N - 1;  i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0;  j < N - i - 1;  j++)
    {
      if (a.data[j] > a.data[j+1])
      {
        int temp  = a[j];
        a[j] = a[j+1];
        a[j+1]= temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return a;
}



template<int... x, int...i>
void g_imp(std::integer_sequence<int, x...>, 
           std::integer_sequence<int, i...> )
{
    constexpr auto array_sorted = bubble_sort_best_sort<x...>();
    f<array_sorted[i]...>();
}


template<int... x>
void g()
{
    auto seq = std::integer_sequence<int, x...>();
    auto idx = std::make_integer_sequence<int, sizeof...(x)>();

    g_imp(seq, idx);
}

int main()
{
  g<4, 7, 2, 9, 3, 7>();
  return 0;
}
```

It's a bit strange that we are forced to define a custom ConstantArray instead of using std::array.
std::array could be fine here if only its "T& operator[]" member would have been constexpr. I checked in the latest draft and it's still not the case, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Just pulled from the [github draft repo](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft), and there's `constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type n) const;` in [array.overview]/3, but no non-const-ref `constexpr` access.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the C++1y relaxations on constant expressions. However, reading the current draft, I wonder if the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in `a[j] = a[j+1]` is legal. Does [expr.const]/2 bullet 7 apply here?

Comment: @DyP I saw the `constexpr const_reference operator[] const` in the draft, but the missing one would really be a `constexpr reference operator[]`. Without it we can't instantiate and write in an std::array in a constexpr function and I don't understand why not. For example it's totally possible to instantiate and write in a std::tuple in a constexpr function because the "get" function is constexpr in the standard (`constexpr T& std::get` (20.4.2.6))

Answer (score 10):

Here is a working solution (my first attempt). Your code would look like this:

```
template<int...N>
void f() 
{
    //this line is just to generate compilation error so that
    //you can see the sorted ints in the error message
    list<N...> generate_error = 0;
}

template<int...N>
void invoke_f_with(list<N...>) 
{
    f<N...>();
}
 
template<int...N>
void g()
{
  invoke_f_with(typename sort<list<N...>>::type{});
}
```

As I intended, the generated error message contains this:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void f() [with int ...N = {2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 9}]’:
```

That shows the integer template arguments are sorted.

The above solution makes use of `sort<>` and `list<>` class templates which are implemented as:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int ...N> 
struct list { using type = list<N...>; };

template<int N, typename IntList> 
struct prepend;

template<int N, int ... ints> 
struct prepend<N, list<ints...>>  : list<N, ints...> {};

namespace detail
{
    template<int A, int B> 
    struct min : std::integral_constant<int, (A < B ? A : B)> {};
    
    template<int A, int B> 
    struct max : std::integral_constant<int, (A > B ? A : B)> {};
    
    template<int i, int ...ints> 
    struct insert_impl : list<i> {};
    
    template<int i, int A, int ...ints> 
    struct insert_impl<i, A, ints...> : prepend<min<i,A>{}, typename insert_impl<max<i,A>{}, ints...>::type> {};
    
    template<int i, typename IntList> 
    struct insert;
    
    template<int i, int ...ints> 
    struct insert<i, list<ints...>> : insert_impl<i, ints...> {};
}

template<typename IntList> 
struct sort : list<> {};

template<int A, int ...N> 
struct sort<list<A,N...>> : detail::insert<A, typename sort<list<N...>>::type> {};
```

[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f1f103a50369ae6).

Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid `sizeof...(N)` recursions?  Recursive depth is often the hard limit of metaprogramming...

Comment: @Yakk: That would be really hard and if it is possible, then the solution would look really complex. In my free time, I would think over this improvement. Thanks for the stimulus. :-)

Comment: A general solution would be some way to take a `N...` and break it into a balanced binary tree.  I cannot think of a way to peel off more than O(1) elements off `N...` in one step.  But we could split `N0, N...` into `N0` and a packaged `N...` in one step, and *return* the packaged `N...`.  Do this twice, and we have removed two elements off the front of `N0, N...` and can return the packaged tail, while adding 1 to the depth of the recursion.  Do that double-remove twice, and we have removed 4.  That may give us "seek-to-offset-k in `N...`" using O(lg(k)) recursive depth...

Comment: @Yakk: I was thinking along the same line. In fact, anybody who wants to avoid `sizeof..(N)` recursions, is *likely* to think the same. *Maybe*, after office, I will post an improved solution.

Comment: Here is a logarithmic seek: http://ideone.com/4ZgVD4 -- probably I should write a logarithmic "split" or "tail" rather than a seek, as `seek<0, N...>` removes the first element from `N...`.

Answer (score 3):

It took a bit to put it together but here is another complete implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <int X>
void print_values() { std::cout << X; }
template <int X, int Y, int... Z>
void print_values() { std::cout << X << ", "; print_values<Y, Z...>(); }
template <int... X>
void print() { print_values<X...>(); std::cout << '\n'; }
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <int...> struct value_list {};

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <int X, typename> struct combine;
template <int X, int...Y>
struct combine<X, value_list<Y...>>
{
    typedef value_list<X, Y...> type;
};

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename, typename> struct merge;

template <int... X>
struct merge<value_list<X...>, value_list<>> {
    typedef value_list<X...> type;
};
template <int... Y>
struct merge<value_list<>, value_list<Y...>> {
    typedef value_list<Y...> type;
};

template <int X0, int... X, int Y0, int... Y>
struct merge<value_list<X0, X...>, value_list<Y0, Y...>> {
    typedef typename std::conditional<(X0 < Y0),
        typename combine<X0,
            typename merge<value_list<X...>,
                           value_list<Y0, Y...>
            >::type
        >::type,
        typename combine<Y0,
            typename merge<value_list<X0, X...>,
                           value_list<Y...>
            >::type
        >::type
    >::type type;
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <int... X> struct sort;

template <int X>
struct sort<X> { typedef value_list<X> type; };
template <int X, int Y>
struct sort<X, Y> { typedef value_list<(X < Y? X: Y), (X < Y? Y: X)> type; };
template <int X, int Y, int... Z>
struct sort<X, Y, Z...> {
    typedef typename merge<typename sort<X, Y>::type,
                           typename sort<Z...>::type>::type type;
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <int... X>
void f()
{
    print<X...>();
}

template <typename> struct g_helper;
template <int... X>
struct g_helper<value_list<X...>>
{
    static void call() { f<X...>(); }
};

template <int... X>
void g()
{
    print<X...>();
    g_helper<typename sort<X...>::type>::call();
}

int main()
{
    g<4,7,2,9,3,7>();
}
```

Comment: Looks a bit complicated (especially the merge), but a good one (+1). The code can be made shorter by avoiding typedefs and typenames, only if `value_list` has a typedef of self (the way I did).

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: And mine is insertion sort. So you have many ways to do the same thing. :D

Comment: @Nawaz: Except your answer is incorrect as insertion sort is not the most efficient way up to constant factors.  Mergesort and quicksort are `O(nlogn)` average case.  Insertion sort is `O(n^2)`.  Appreciate your time anyway.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: Although the sort  I attempted resembles mergesort it actually isn't: it always chops off two elements and merges them with the list seen so far. I think the code I posted has `O(n*n)` complexity but I'm currently not quite ready to either proof this complexity and/or improve on it.

Comment: You're right.  You fooled me.  `merge` looks like it merges two sorted lists to me.  Given that, I think it is pretty easy to adjust `sort` for the big case to split the list approximately in half and then `merge<sort<A...>, sort<B...>>`

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: It is as efficient as mergesort/quicksort, at runtime, because the computation is done at compile time, so if you can wait for a bit longer in the compilation phase, that is okay.

Comment: @Nawaz: :) Actually, compile-time performance is a major issue for a lot of people in C++ metaprogramming.  Recall that for a 1000 item list, insertion sort is about 100 times slower than mergesort/quicksort.  About the ratio between 20 minutes and 2 days.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: Well, I didn't come up with a quick approach to split the lists in the `sort()` but, yes, once this is done correctly, the [compile-time] complexity should be something like `O(n log n)` although the compiler may do something funny to the types, too.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Yes this assumes `merge` is `O(n)`, but due to the head-tail recursion it could actually be `O(n^2)` if the compiler copies the tails for each iteration, which in practice I guess it will.  Need to pass the tail as an index range somehow.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: with respect to the compile-time complexities, I'd think it either shouldn't matter or you are misusing the language. For example, I can't see why it would be necessary to sort a list of 1000 integers at compile-time. I can see that it might be useful to order a couple dozens integers but beyond that I would expect a different too to be used.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Use case: Suppose you have a set of integers produced by iterating over a constexpr function `f(0),f(1),...f(999)`.  You want to lookup at run-time if an integer is a member of that set.  So you need to call f 1000 times to produce the values and then sort them into a list that then constant-initializes an array.  That array is then part of the program image and binary search is applied to it at run-time to return the result.  There are better algorithms, but the idea of generating the lookup array at compile-time with metaprogramming is a valid use-case in my opinion.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: I stand with what I said: Meta-programming isn't a means to itself although I realize that many people treat it that way. If you want to use a functional programming language, use Haskell or something similar. The purpose of meta-programming in C++ is to sort out interfaces to functions and classes, e.g., to make variadic functions work. Using 1000 elements in this case is a strong indication that something went dramatically wrong in the design a long time ago.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: There is no way to implement the use case I stated without using metaprogramming in C++ (outside of writing a second program that automatically generates C++ code, and such an architecture has much worse drawbacks).  The use case has nothing to do with functional vs imperative programming, it just happens that it is the only way to do it in C++ as yet.  I am in favor of and welcome future versions of C++ that allow a more imperative-style of metaprogramming.

Comment: (such advances will most likely come in the form of relaxations of the constraints on constexpr functions and literal types)

Comment: This looks like a horribly inefficient merge sort, as it splits the list into a list of 2 elements, and a list of N-2 elements, and recurses on each sub list.  O(n^2) total computation, O(n) depth?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that transform the list to [skew heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_heap) then to sorted list.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <class T, T... s>
using iseq = std::integer_sequence<T, s...>;

template <class T, T v>
using ic = std::integral_constant<T, v>;

template <bool b>
using bool_cond_t = std::conditional_t<b, std::true_type, std::false_type>;

// define compare function
template <class T, T v1, T v2>
constexpr auto ic_less_impl(ic<T, v1>, ic<T, v2>) -> bool_cond_t<(v1 < v2)>;
template <class ic1, class ic2>
using ic_less = decltype(ic_less_impl(ic1(), ic2()));

// data structure for null
struct nil {};

// get first element from sequence
template <class T, T v, T... s>
constexpr auto iseq_front_impl(iseq<T, v, s...>) -> ic<T, v>;

template <class T>
constexpr auto iseq_front_impl(iseq<T>) -> nil;

template <class seq>
using iseq_front = decltype(iseq_front_impl(seq()));

// remove first element from sequence
template <class T, T v, T... s>
constexpr auto iseq_pop_front_impl(iseq<T, v, s...>) -> iseq<T, s...>;

template <class seq>
using iseq_pop_front = decltype(iseq_pop_front_impl(seq()));

// append element into sequence
template <class T, T v, T... s>
constexpr auto iseq_append_impl(iseq<T, s...>, ic<T, v>) -> iseq<T, s..., v>;

template <class T, T v>
constexpr auto iseq_append_impl(nil, ic<T, v>) -> iseq<T, v>;

template <class seq, class c>
using iseq_append = decltype(iseq_append_impl(seq(), c()));

// check whether the sequence is empty
template <class seq>
using iseq_is_empty = bool_cond_t<std::is_same<iseq_front<seq>, nil>::value>;

// define structure of skew heap
template <class X, class L, class R>
struct skew_heap {};

// get the top of skew heap
template <class X, class L, class R>
constexpr auto skh_get_top_impl(skew_heap<X, L, R>) -> X;

template <class H>
using skh_get_top = decltype(skh_get_top_impl(H()));

// get left subtree of skew heap
template <class X, class L, class R>
constexpr auto skh_get_left_impl(skew_heap<X, L, R>) -> L;

template <class H>
using skh_get_left = decltype(skh_get_left_impl(H()));

// get right subtree of skew heap
template <class X, class L, class R>
constexpr auto skh_get_right_impl(skew_heap<X, L, R>) -> R;

template <class H>
using skh_get_right = decltype(skh_get_right_impl(H()));

// check whether skew heap is empty
template <class H>
using skh_is_empty = bool_cond_t<std::is_same<H, nil>::value>;

// skew heap merge function
template <class H1, class H2>
constexpr auto skh_merge_impl(H1, H2) -> decltype(auto) {
    if constexpr (skh_is_empty<H1>::value) {
        return H2{};
    } else if constexpr (skh_is_empty<H2>::value) {
        return H1{};
    } else {
        using x1 = skh_get_top<H1>;
        using l1 = skh_get_left<H1>;
        using r1 = skh_get_right<H1>;

        using x2 = skh_get_top<H2>;
        using l2 = skh_get_left<H2>;
        using r2 = skh_get_right<H2>;

        if constexpr (ic_less<x2, x1>::value) {
            using new_r2 = decltype(skh_merge_impl(H1(), r2()));
            return skew_heap<x2, new_r2, l2> {};
        } else {
            using new_r1 = decltype(skh_merge_impl(r1(), H2()));
            return skew_heap<x1, new_r1, l1>{};
        }
    }
}

template <class H1, class H2>
using skh_merge = decltype(skh_merge_impl(H1(), H2()));

// push an element into skew heap
template <class H1, class IC1>
using skh_push = skh_merge<H1, skew_heap<IC1, nil, nil>>;

// pop an element from skew heap
template <class H>
using skh_pop = skh_merge<skh_get_left<H>, skh_get_right<H>>;

// convert sequence to skew heap
template <class H, class seq>
constexpr auto skh_heapify_impl(H, seq) -> decltype(auto) {
    if constexpr (iseq_is_empty<seq>::value) {
        return H{};
    } else {
        using val = iseq_front<seq>;
        return skh_heapify_impl(skh_push<H, val>{}, iseq_pop_front<seq>{});
    }
}

template <class seq>
using skh_heapify = decltype(skh_heapify_impl(nil(), seq()));

// convert skew heap to sorted sequence
template <class H, class seq>
constexpr auto skh_to_sortlist_impl(H, seq) -> decltype(auto) {
    if constexpr (skh_is_empty<H>::value) {
        return seq{};
    } else {
        using val = skh_get_top<H>;
        return skh_to_sortlist_impl(skh_pop<H>{}, iseq_append<seq, val>{});
    }
}

template <class H>
using skh_to_sortlist = decltype(skh_to_sortlist_impl(H(), nil()));

// sort sequence
template <class seq>
using sort_iseq = skh_to_sortlist<skh_heapify<seq>>;

template <int... s>
void f() {
    for (auto x : {s...})
        std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

template <int... s>
void g_helper(iseq<int, s...>) {
    f<s...>();
}

template <int... s>
void g() {
    g_helper(sort_iseq<iseq<int, s...>>{});
}

int main(void) {
    g<2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 6, 7, 1>();
    return 0;
}
```

It's also able to be implemented in c++11.

[c++11 solution and online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ee659350b417eee)