# What are constexpr containers in C++17?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I want to make a class that has methods like `std::map`, but it should be sorted at compile time. Which `constexpr` containers are suited to store  keys `template<class K>` and values `template<class V>`?

std::vector does not meet these requirements.

UPD: We found that `std::array` has a lot of constexpr methods. And it's enough for my problem to use `std::array<std::pair<K, V> >`.
But the question holds.

Comment: Compile time can't do memory allocation.

Comment: What do you mean by a _constexpr container_? Here is a list of all the [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: Ok, but what about `int array[const N]`? I solved one problem where I made a lot of matrices at compile time. The only possible options for K and V are `string` and `int`.

Comment: Constexpr containers should have constexpr methods.

Comment: So it sounds like you are looking for something like `std::array`, a `constexpr` function to create pre-sorted from an initializer list, and a few extra functions to do lookups based on a particular field of the elements (same field used for sorting)?

Comment: @InFamousX Why assemble matrices at compile time ? Loading from a file is much more natural.

Comment: @liliscent: If there is a recursive definition, generation in code is quite natural.

Comment: @liliscent Because I study c++ and that was a problem from a book.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19559808/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt Using compile time computation to compute data (matrix) is really crazy IMO. I'd rather compute them in Python and copy it to source code.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Exactly.

Comment: @liliscent: That only means you like python better than C++.  It doesn't mean the rest of the world needs to do it the same way.

Comment: @liliscent, You can accomplish a lot just by sticking `constexpr` in front of functions. Compile-time calculations aren't as crazy as they used to be.

Comment: I also enjoy template programming, but here my point is the computation of pure data, like matrix. I don't think it worth slowing down compilation with no realistic gain. Loading data from file is the correct choice. @chris

Comment: @liliscent If you have a small LUT with a recursive definition as Ben mentioned, it can be a self-documenting and very clear option. You are entitled to your opinion but "there is no purpose for compile-time arrays" is a stretch.

Answer (score 10):

Most C++ standard library containers are not useful as constexpr. AFAIK only first 64 bits of `std::bitset` and `std::array` (of any length) are fillable compile time.

Do not concentrate on such performance optimizations before the program itself is ready. Filling large `std::array` compile-time was not too hard in C++11 using variadic template functions.

Example of how to fill array of 4 ints (each representing one of 6 colors) compile time using variadic templates:

```
constexpr int ColorCount = 6;
constexpr int PositionCount = 4;

using Positions = std::array<int, PositionCount>;

template <int N>
struct PositionsFiller
{
    template <typename T, typename ...Tn>
    static constexpr Positions fill(T packed, Tn ...rest)
    {
        return PositionsFiller<N - 1>::fill(packed / ColorCount, packed % ColorCount, rest...);
    }
};

template <>
struct PositionsFiller<1>
{
    template <typename T, typename ...Tn>
    static constexpr Positions fill(T last, Tn ...rest)
    {
        return Positions{last, rest...};
    }
};

constexpr Positions pos666(PositionsFiller<PositionCount>::fill(666));
```

In C++17 same can be done with simple loop since requirements to constexpr are relaxed and there variadic templates are not needed:

```
constexpr int ColorCount = 6;
constexpr int PositionCount = 4;

using Positions = std::array<int, PositionCount>;

static constexpr Positions fillPositions(int packed)
{
    Positions ret{};
    for (Positions::size_type i = ret.size(); i > 0; --i)
    {
        ret[i-1] = packed % ColorCount;
        packed /= ColorCount;
    }
    return ret;
}

constexpr Positions pos666(fillPositions(666));
```

Note that doing complex preparations compile time can slow down compilations. That may be annoying when module is still under development. Better can be to fill usual mutable array at start of program and later to replace it with optimizations like compile-time filling.

Comment: I haven't had any problems using std::array in constexpr functions with any number of elements. That would include thinks like make_sorted_array which would allow one to pass elements as parameter and return sorted array object. Even std::map like tree should be possible to implement using tuple as memory allocator. (never tried tuple allocator but basic idea seems to be workable for any constexpr stl like container)

Comment: Any size limit is entirely implementation specific - remember that constexpr is a hint, not a directive. The compiler may choose not to actually execute it at compile time, for any reason.