# What does the standard say about char arrays as template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, linkage

During my research for an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57003010/9883438) I found (I did not know that before) that gcc and clang allow `char` arrays to be template arguments if they are declared `static`. E.g. this code compiles with gcc and clang:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int N, const char (&string)[N]>
auto foo()
{
    if constexpr (string[0] == 'i')
        return 0;
    else
        return 3.14f;
}

void bar()
{
    static constexpr char string1[] = "int";
    static constexpr char string2[] = "float";

    auto i = foo<sizeof(string1), string1>();
    auto f = foo<sizeof(string2), string2>();

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(i), int>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(f), float>);
}
```

MSVC also allows that. However, to make it work with MSVC, I have to declare the two strings in the global namespace. Then it works just as well.

So my question is: What does the standard say about this? Which compiler (if any) is right?

---

### Update:

This issue has been fixed in VS 2019 version 16.4 (msvc v19.24): https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/341639/very-fragile-ice.html

Comment: [Issue Reproduced](https://godbolt.org/z/boxiaB).

Comment: Note that this only works with *string literals*, if you create an actual array of char as a template argument, e.g.  `static constexpr char p[]  = { 'i','n','t' }`, it will fail under MSVC as per [this bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C:-Cannot-index-array-passed-as-templa/946250)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a change from C++14 to C++17 that looks like MSVS hasn't caught up with.  Previously in [[temp.arg.nontype]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.arg.nontype) a non type argument had to be

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> - for a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression ([expr.const]) of the type of the template-parameter; or
> - the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
> - **a constant expression ([expr.const]) that designates the address of a complete object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage** or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as & id-expression, where the id-expression is the name of an object or function, except that the & may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding template-parameter is a reference; or
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value ([conv.ptr]); or
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null member pointer value ([conv.mem]); or
> - a pointer to member expressed as described in [expr.unary.op]; or
> - a constant expression of type `std::nullptr_t`.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

and because of bullet 3 you could not use a block scope variable as block scope variables have no linkage per [[basic.link]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.link#10)

> Names not covered by these rules have no linkage. Moreover, except as noted, a name declared at block scope has no linkage.

In C++17 this changes.  [[temp.arg.nontype]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype) now has

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a converted constant expression of the type of the template-parameter. For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - a subobject,
> - a temporary object,
> - a string literal,
> - the result of a typeid expression, or
> - a predefined *­*­func_­_­ variable.

This now allows you to use a block scope static variable

Comment: How to report issues like these to the MSVC developers?

Comment: @j00hi IIRC you can submit bug reports directly through MSVS.

Comment: Done => [A block scope static variable should be a valid template-argument for a non-type template-parameter, but isn't in MSVC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/643307/a-block-scope-static-variable-should-be-a-valid-te.html) (Feel free to suggest edits to the wording/phrasing/description of the issue!)