# In C++, can we sort an array at compile time without using std

Tags: c++, sorting, templates

Consider we have an array of strings:

```
static constexpr char *sCommands[] = {
    "AAA",
    "CCC",
    "BBB",
    "DDD",
    ...
};
```

Can we get it sorted at compile time (or get another sorted array) **without using std**? Template is allowed.

**Edit**

Some background:
This list will be binary-searched so it has to be sorted. The intention for doing the compile-time sorting is: There will be a lot of macros wrapping these items in this list and it's hard to maintain.

For example:

```
static constexpr char *sCommands[] = {
#if FEATURE_1
    "AAA",
#endif
#if FEATURE_2
    "BBB",
#endif
#if FEATURE_1
    "CCC",
#endif
#if FEATURE_2
    "DDD",
#endif
    ...
};
```

In real cases, this is more complex with nested macros, which makes the code hard to read and maintain.

I would be better if we can put the items under the macros:

```
static constexpr char *sCommands[] = {
#if FEATURE_1
    "AAA",
    "CCC",
#endif
#if FEATURE_2
    "BBB",
    "DDD",
#endif
    ...
};
```

Comment: It'd be far easier to sort this in your text editor. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'd suggest copying the contents of the array out to a separate .txt file, then doing `sort <file.txt >sorted_file.txt`, and then inserting the contents of `sorted_file.txt` back into your .cpp file.

Comment: Thanks for helping :) I made an update for the intention of doing this.

Comment: You can write your own `constexpr` sort algorithm. Not easy though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [constexpr initialization of array to sort contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559808/constexpr-initialization-of-array-to-sort-contents)

Comment: Just an aside - that you might want to address in production -: your `sCommands` entries are modifiable. https://godbolt.org/z/EGYjaoafE