# Inheritance together with parameter template packs. What is the trick?

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I have seen some code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19209751/877329) using recursive "inheritance" to mangle template parameter packs. What is the idea behind that construction? How does it work?

Comment: Are you asking for the motivation of that approach?  Or are you asking how does it work?

Comment: The latter. I saw a similar approach on another topic.

Comment: @user877329 Hard to explain it with words :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface**

Although template recursion is often a necessity, there is nothing that necessarily requires the use of inheritance.  That said, it has become fairly standard to use the pattern:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_trait : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_trait<T, std::enable_if_t<some_predicate>> : std::true_type {};
```

That is, the standard has provided the types `std::{true,false}_type` for convenience as they have static `constexpr` `value` members.  Such a pattern strongly suggests that recursive inheritance is common and encouraged.

**Recursive inheritance**

Suppose I want to determine if a parameter pack contains a parameter of type `T`.  To do so, I'm going to create an implementation `struct` of the type:

```
template <bool B, typename T, typename ... ARGS>
struct pack_with_type_impl;
```

The non-type parameter `B` is a "matching" parameter; `T` is the parameter which we're interested in matching against; and `ARGS...` is the parameter pack.

We will use specializations of this template to handle various cases.

**Empty parameter pack**

Let's take the case where the parameter pack is empty.  In that case the specialization looks like:

```
template <bool B, typename T>
struct pack_with_type_impl<B,T> : std::false_type {};
```

There's obviously no type `T` in an empty parameter pack, so the specialization inherits from `std::false_type`.

**Matching parameter pack**

Now let's say that it has been determined that a parameter of type `T` *does* exist in the parameter pack.  In that case, the specialization looks like:

```
template <typename T, typename ... ARGS>
struct pack_with_type_impl<true, T, ARGS...> : std::true_type {};
```

**The Recursion**

Now's the fun part.  Till now we have done no recursion because the above cases represent terminating conditions: one where the parameter pack is empty, so there's nothing more to do; and one where a match has been found so there's nothing more to do.  But let's now do the part where twe *have not yet* found a match.  In that case, we would have something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename H, typename ... TAIL>
struct pack_with_type_impl<false, T, H, TAIL...> :
   pack_with_type_impl<std::is_same<T,H>::value, T, TAIL...> {};
```

What?  In this case, the match was `false`, so it will then inherit from the template *with one fewer parameter provided*.  That is, the parameter `H`, corresponding to the head of the parameter pack, has been stripped off, so that it is tested by itself, and the types `T`, and `TAIL...` are preserved for future processing if necessary.  The `std::is_same` functionality simply checks if the types are identical.  The inheritance chain keeps going, stripping off the head each time, until one of the terminating conditions is reached.

As an example, let's say that I want to check if a parameter pack has a type `int`, and the arguments I'm providing are: `char,double,float`.  The inheritance chain would look like this:

```
pack_with_type_impl<false,int,char,double,float> 
  ==> pack_with_type_impl<false,int,double,float> 
    ==> pack_with_type_impl<false,int,float> 
      ==> pack_with_type_impl<false,int> # and since the parameter pack is empty now...
        ==> std::false_type
```

On the other hand, if I had provided the arguments `char,int,double`, the inheritance chain would be:

```
pack_with_type_impl<false,int,char,int,float> 
  ==> pack_with_type_impl<false,int,int,float> 
    ==> pack_with_type_impl<true,int,float> # and since the first argument is true 
      ==> std::true_type
```

**Comments**

There are certainly more elegant ways to do this.  For starters, I would probably create a few alias templates along the lines of:

```
template <typename ... ARGS>
using has_int = pack_with_type_impl<false,int,ARGS...>;
```

so that I can call:

```
template <typename ... ARGS>
void increment_int(std::tuple<ARGS...>& tup) {
   static_assert(has_int<ARGS...>::value,
                 "Can only call increment_int on tuples with an int type!");
   ...
}
```

but this is a first attempt at explaining this tricky issue.

Answer (score 1):

In generic code, you cannot create a class with N direct members. You can however create a class with one direct member and `N-1` inherited members, ending the recursion by specializing for `N==1`.

Example: say you want to create a class such that `Foo<int, double, std::string>` contains 3 member functions `void Foo::f(int); void Foo::f(int); void Foo::f(std::string)`. This isn't directly possible because N=3. However, you can derive `Foo<int, double, std::string>` from `Foo<double, std::string>` and add one member `void f(int)`.

```
template<typename HEAD, typename... Tail>
class Foo : public Foo<Tail...>
{
    public: void f(HEAD h) { std::cout << h; }
};

template<typename HEAD>
class Foo<HEAD>
{
    public: void f(HEAD h) { std::cout << h; }
};
```